# Frame spaces and caption

Tags: spacing, framed

I have question about frames, how to add text under the frame and spaces like this? I have more frames and all are the same.
I need this:
[image]

And I have:
[image]

Code fragment:

```
\begin{framed}
\begin{thm} Neka su f i g realne funkcije, takve da je kompozicija $f \circ g$ definirana. Neka je također g derivabilna u $x_0$, a f u točki $g(x_0)$. Tada vrijedi
\begin{myequation}
    \mathbf{(vi)} \quad (f\circ g)'(x_0) =f'(g(x_0)) \cdot g'(x_0)
\end{myequation}
\end{thm}
\end{framed} 
Dokaz ovog teorema može se vidjeti u \textit{Dodatku 4.1}
```

Comment: Please show  some code (MWE) to help us help you.

Comment: Please make the code compilable (make it a MWE).

Comment: I fixed question is know ok?

Comment: @AnaLeko a MWE consist of everything necessary to compile your snippet. Starting from `\documentclass` ending at `\end{document}` with all necessary packages (so only those needed, no more no less).

Comment: Do you use `ntheorem` and its `framed` option, per chance?

Comment: @Bernard the above code-fragment shows a `\begin{framed}...\end{framed}` so it doesn't look like it... But you can provide an answer using it, of course :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution with the `framed` option of `ntheorem` (which uses framed-the-package):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage{geometry}%
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{framed} %
\usepackage[framed, thref, amsmath, thmmarks]{ntheorem} %

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\theoremstyle{plain}
\theoremheaderfont{\bfseries\upshape}
\theorembodyfont{\itshape}
\colorlet{framecolor}{NavyBlue!65}
\def\theoremframecommand{\setlength{\fboxrule}{1.6pt}\fcolorbox{framecolor}{white}}
\theoremframepostskip{0cm}
\theoreminframepreskip{5pt}
\theoreminframepostskip{4pt}
\theoremindent = 1cm\theoremrightindent = 1cm
\newshadedtheorem{thm}{Teorem}[chapter]
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\appendix%
\setcounter{chapter}{4}
\setcounter{thm}{3}
\setcounter{equation}{17}
\begin{thm} Neka su f i g realne funkcije, takve da je kompozicija $f ∘ g$ definirana. Neka je također g derivabilna u $x₀$, a f u točki $g(x₀)$. Tada vrijedi%
\let\belowdisplayskip\belowdisplayshortskip\let\abovedisplayskip\abovedisplayshortskip
  \begin{equation}
    \mathbf{(vi)} \quad (f ∘ g)'(x₀) =f'(g(x₀)) · g'(x₀)
  \end{equation}
\end{thm}
\hspace*{\dimexpr\fboxrule + \theoremindent + \fontdimen4\font-\parindent}
Dokaz ovog teorema može se vidjeti u \textit{Dodatku 4.1}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to change the vertical space between the frame and the content? Other than that, best answer so far.

Comment: @Skillmon: Sorry for not checking the code (my editor does some pretty display for a better readability of formulae, and I often forget to copy the saved version). Fixed. Thanks for pointing it! Concerning the vertical spacing, there's a tool for that. I'll update the answer in a moment.

Comment: @Skillmon: I've added  the parameters which allow to modify the inner vertical spacings.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

\newtheorem{thm}{Thm:}

\begin{document}

\begin{framed}
    \begin{thm} Neka su f i g realne funkcije, takve da je kompozicija $f \circ g$ definirana. Neka je također g derivabilna u $x_0$, a f u točki $g(x_0)$. Tada vrijedi
        \begin{align*}
            \mathbf{(vi)} \quad (f\circ g)'(x_0) =f'(g(x_0)) \cdot g'(x_0)
        \end{align*}
    \end{thm}
\end{framed} 

\hspace{.1in} Dokaz ovog teorema može se vidjeti u \textit{Dodatku 4.1}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: That does not answer the question as the horizontal space within the framed part is not altered.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\FrameSep=3em

\begin{document}
\begin{framed}
    this is a nice test.
    \begin{align}
        E = mc^2
        \label{eqn:emc}
    \end{align}
\end{framed}
\hskip\dimexpr\FrameSep+\FrameRule\relax
Test
\end{document}
```

The drawback is, that the `framed`-package uses `\FrameSep` for vertical and horizontal spacing.

[image: results]